# How to set a generic value to NULL?

Tags: c++

I am doing a 2-3 tree class, and my BNode class is a generic one, so it can store any kind of data. So I come upon this situation: I have a 3-node (with 2 values and 3 child pointers) and in theoretical I have to break that 3-node into a 2 2 nodes, each node can only have one value and 2 child pointers. Here comes the question, in programming, do you have to create 2 new nodes, each node will hold each value of the 3-node ? OR can you only create one new node, and reuse the 3-node by set the second value to NULL ? and if you can, how would you set NULL to it, consider that the value that you have is a generic one. Thank you.

Comment: Well, you can use pointer to null, otherwise use your value + bool "is filled".

Comment: If I code this, and if each node colud have no more than 8 values, I used array of 8 values + byte is_filled and used & operator to get each bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your 2-node and 3-node are different types? In that case I would definitely create 2 new 2-nodes.

Otherwise you could use [boost::Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)

Answer (score -1):

i think both are possible... but i think it will be better if you use 3-node structure for the whole tree.. you could use flag (with bool or int or anything) to determine its kind (3-node or 2-node)